# Investigating the effects of a price increase

Tags: statistical-significance

I’m trying to analyse the effects of an increase in price of certain sku’s. I’m not certain on the best way to go about this.

So far I’m looking at the changes in sales and orders over a period before and after a price increase. Then using a T Test to see if there’s a significant difference in the variances between the group of items who’s price has increased and a group unaffected by the price change.

Any suggestions on where to go with this would be appreciated

Comment: The t-test is a test of a difference in means, not variances. Many people would be content to see if the average whatever has changed after the price increase. Interestingly, though, you mention investigating both sales and orders. If those are related (I suspect they are) there's a way of using that fact to get a better chance of detecting a difference between the two groups.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your answer Dave.  Would testing the difference in the mean of the variances (if that makes sense) be a valid use?  What would that way be?

Comment: Please explain what "difference in the mean of the variances" means.

Comment: for example, one set has 10 items, the average of their variances between period 1 and period 2  is x and the other set has 15 items and the average of the variance of sales between period 1 and period 2 is y. Could I test the difference in those two means?

Comment: That approach does not make sense to me, but what would you hope to get from it? It will be helpful if you can identify what you want to say. Then we can get into what statistical methods are appropriate.

Comment: Im hoping to be able to answer the questions:

Has the price increase affected sales , relative to the rest of the business
Has the price increase affected orders , relative to the rest of the business
And perhaps later has it affected the volume/ type of customers that are ordering 

hopefully by answering these questions i'll be able to say if increasing the price was a success or not

Comment: What are your questions...?

Comment: sorry , theyre in the edit above

Comment: So you have four groups: ski sales before the increase, ski sales after the increase, the rest of the business before the increase, and the rest of the business after the increase, correct?

Comment: Well, sku ( as in products ) but yes essentially.

Comment: In that case, find the differences in your response variables of interest (after minus before) and then do a two-sample t-test. There are many other approaches, but this is the simple way and very likely what your boss expects to see. The suggestions like Bayesian time series and VAR might be reasonable, but they’re major rabbit holes for you at this point.

Comment: On second thought, you don’t have a natural pairing for a subject before and then after the price change, do you?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a Bayesian structural time series model with daily/weekly/monthly/whatever sales as the series of interest and price as a covariate.

The big advantage of a multivariate time-series approach would be the ability to account for other things that might be affecting sales before and after the price change as well, e.g., seasonal effects, sales of related items, whatever you think might be relevant. If the price change had a significant effect, then you would expect to see a negative coefficient and a high inclusion probability for that feature.

See [here](http://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2017/07/fitting-bayesian-structural-time-series.html) and [here](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/) for some discussions of the technique and its implementation in R.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run a VAR and then an impulse response function!

This is a good example:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-inconvenient-statistic/

The author explains how to run the VAR function, step by step!

I hope it helps :)